# Stop body from going to the fixed Menu

Tags: css

When i resize my page, my body content goes to the fixed menu area.

I'm using pixels and percentages, how can i prevent that?

http://jsfiddle.net/D6ZCh/

```
<div class="menu">menu</div>
<div class="body">body content</div>

.menu{
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
}

.body{
    background-color: yellow;
    float: right;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U could use `width: calc(100% - 200px);` on `.body`

Example:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skeurentjes/D6ZCh/1/)

ps: modern browsers only

Comment: Thanks, i didn't knew about that.